# Scrapy or Beautifoulsoup for a custom scraper?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrapy, logic

I need guidance in developing a scraper.

I need to build a custom scraper that retrieves all products from 3 e-commerce websites.

I built the PoC scraper with Scrapy, however, there is a flow with this scraper:

**The scraper needs to crawl a given category up to scrape depth level 3 in order to reach and access the pages that I need, which are at depth level 1.**

For example, *the crawl needs to follow this sequence*:

1. Start: **domain.com**
2. **domain.com/category/sub_categry/mini_sub_category**
3. **domain.com/product1** and **domain.com/product2**

The urls for **product1** and **product2** are only accessible by reaching depth level 2 (crawling sub_categories).

My question is if I can customize scrapy to follow this sequence automatically **OR** do I need to custom built a scraper with Beautifouldsoup and provide each sub_category manually and let bs4 to start scraping from there?

**This is my Scrapy code**

```
class DomainsSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = 'domains'
allowed_domains = ['www.amazon.com']
start_urls = ['http://www.amazon.com/']


rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(canonicalize=True, unique=True),follow=True, callback="parse_items")]


def parse_items(self, response):

    # create the soup for the domain
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    #check if proxy is working
    if not soup.title.string:
        yield Request(url=response.url, dont_filter=True)


#extract the title      
    heading_1_raw = response.selector.xpath('//h1/text()').extract()
    heading_1_strip = [s.strip() for s in heading_1_raw]
    heading_1 = []


    for h1_text in range(0, len(heading_1_strip)):
        if str(heading_1_strip[h1_text]) != "":
            heading_1.append(heading_1_strip[h1_text])


    price_raw = response.selector.xpath('//p[contains(@class, "product-new-price")]//text()').extract()


    product_code_text = soup.find_all(string=re.compile("Cod produs"))


    yield {
        'url' : response.url,
        'page_title': soup.title.string,
        #'h1': h1s[0],
        'h1' : heading_1[0],
        'price' : price_raw,
        'product_code' : product_code_text

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want can easily be done using scrapy, you just need to give your `CrawlSpider` a list of rules which describe how to do the crawling.

Something as simple as this might do the trick:

```
rules = [
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['/category/'])),
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['/product']), callback='parse_items')
]
```

If you're having trouble understanding or modifying this code, I suggest reading up on [rules](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules) and [link extractors](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#topics-link-extractors).

Also, there is no need to use BeautifulSoup in your spiders, the built-in parsel selectors are more than capable of extracting any data you want.

Comment: Thank you! I will look into it and let you know.

Comment: Hi, been looking into this, but I can't seem to wrap my head around the product URL. I mean how can I pass the argument to accept and scrape products if there are different products from different categories.

For example, how can instruct it to accept product links like 
`'/fossil-watch'` and 
`'/dell-laptop'` 
when there is no correlation between the product pages? Been looking into it for some days and I still can't figure it out.

Comment: It depends on the specifics of the site, really. If the url's share a common pattern, you can probably use `allow`, like in my example (takes regular expressions), if the product links are located in a similar location, you can use `restrict_xpaths` or `restrict_css`, and you can combine these ways, both with each other, and other arguments to `LinkExtractor`.